# How to change desktop wallpaper in Intune using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, intune

I'm trying to code a program where it will push the desktop wallpaper that I have saved locally on my computer to apply a desktop wallpaper. I've tried to code and the resulting work! Just want to know if this will work on other laptops as I am using my path which is located on my computer.

```
$imgPath="C:\Users\EdricVillanueva\Create IT\Create IT Team Site - Documents\08 Graphics\Create IT Wallpaper.jpg" 
$code = @' 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
namespace Win32{ 
    
     public class Wallpaper{ 
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)] 
         static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction , int uParam , string lpvParam , int fuWinIni) ; 
         
         public static void SetWallpaper(string thePath){ 
            SystemParametersInfo(20,0,thePath,3); 
         }
    }
 } 
'@

add-type $code 

#Apply the Change to the system 
[Win32.Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper($imgPath)
```

Anything I can edit to change $imgPath.

Kindly note that the Create IT is from a onedrive folder.

Basically, other user has already onedrive on their laptop but I want to get the string of their username so that I can use their name instead of "EdricVillanueva"

Comment: You would most likely need to place it on a network location the remote computer has access to or, copy the image over to the remote machine first then apply it.

Comment: Hi Abraham. Thanks for commenting. Basically, we are using one drive as a  storage location. Mind showing how I can do this with onedrive?